# How can I validate the string value of a key using JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm finding it difficult to understand how to validate different types of responses with different set of validation. I'm just put an example code and that might make sense then trying to explain it.

Example dataset:

```
responses: [
   { type: 'user', age: 5 }
   { type: 'admi', auth: {...} }
]
```

json schema sample:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "user": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": { "type": "string" },
                "age": { "type": "number" }
            }
            "required": ["age"]
        },
        "admin": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": { "type": "string" },
                "auth": { "type": "object" }
            }
            "required": ["auth"]
        }
    },
  "responses": {
    "type": "array",
    "anyOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/user" }
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/admi" }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can these be validated depending on type (not `string, number`, but `'user', 'admi'`)?

Comment: The language here is a little bit confused. The type of object is something you have defined, and you're on the right track by using `anyOf`. I'll form an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be looking for validation keywords whcih apply to strings or any types in your instance. In the latest version of JSON Schema, you can find [`const`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.3).

You would add a const key word as follows for your user definition...

```
...
    "user": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "type": { "type": "string", "const": "user" },
            "age": { "type": "number" }
        }
        "required": ["age"]
    },
...
```

If `const` isn't available to you because you need to use an older version of JSON Schema, you could use `enum` which is practically the sam but you woule encase the string "user" inside an array as the value for the `enum` key word.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm part of the team that work on JSON Schema. Feel free to join the slack channel if you'd like to ask questions out of scope for SO.